# How to apply "first" and "last" functions to columns while using group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame and I would like to group it by a particular column (or, in other words, by values from a particular column). I can do it in the following way: `grouped = df.groupby(['ColumnName'])`.

I imagine the result of this operation as a table in which some cells can contain sets of values instead of single values. To get a usual table (i.e. a table in which every cell contains only one a single value) I need to indicate what function I want to use to transform the sets of values in the cells into single values.

For example I can replace sets of values by their sum, or by their minimal or maximal value. I can do it in the following way: `grouped.sum()` or `grouped.min()` and so on.

Now I want to use different functions for different columns. I figured out that I can do it in the following way: `grouped.agg({'ColumnName1':sum, 'ColumnName2':min})`.

However, because of some reasons I cannot use `first`. In more details, `grouped.first()` works, but `grouped.agg({'ColumnName1':first, 'ColumnName2':first})` does not work. As a result I get a NameError: `NameError: name 'first' is not defined`. So, my question is: Why does it happen and how to resolve this problem.

**ADDED**

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) I found the following example:

```
grouped['D'].agg({'result1' : np.sum, 'result2' : np.mean})
```

May be I also need to use `np`? But in my case python does not recognize "np". Should I import it?

Comment: You don't need `np`, it'll work with plain old `sum` (only less efficiently). numpy is imported with pandas (if you `import pandas as pd` it's `pd.np`) but most people will also import it separately for convenience.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think the issue is that there are two different `first` methods which share a name but act differently, one is for [groupby objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) and [another for a Series/DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) (to do with timeseries).

To replicate the behaviour of the groupby `first` method over a DataFrame using `agg` you could use `iloc[0]` (which gets the first row in each group (DataFrame/Series) by index):

```
grouped.agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
```

For example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [2]: g = df.groupby(0)

In [3]: g.first()
Out[3]: 
   1
0   
1  2
3  4

In [4]: g.agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[4]: 
   1
0   
1  2
3  4
```

*Analogously you can replicate `last` using `iloc[-1]`.*

Note: This will works column-wise, et al:

```
g.agg({1: lambda x: x.iloc[0]})
```

*In older version of pandas you could would use the irow method (e.g. `x.irow(0)`, see previous edits.*

---

A couple of updated notes:

This is better done using the [`nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) groupby method, which is much faster >=0.13:

```
g.nth(0)  # first
g.nth(-1)  # last
```

*You have to take care a little, as the default behaviour for `first` and `last` ignores NaN rows... and IIRC for DataFrame groupbys it was broken pre-0.13... there's a `dropna` option for `nth`.*

You can use the strings rather than built-ins (though IIRC pandas spots it's the `sum` builtin and applies `np.sum`):

```
grouped['D'].agg({'result1' : "sum", 'result2' : "mean"})
```

Comment: Just in case it's useful to anyone, according to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html), `irow` is now deprecated (`x.iloc[0]` does the trick instead)

Comment: @cd98 Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated this with the newer syntax :)

Comment: I'm confused with [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation); it states: `Aggregating functions are ones that reduce the dimension of the returned objects, for example: mean, sum, size, count, std, var, sem, describe, first, last, nth, min, max.` So what are they talking about?

Comment: In some sense there's three types of mapping here: aggregation, apply and filter (the above is kind of a filter, although it uses the agg verb). This is complicated thing is that you can use **either** agg or apply to get the `.iloc[0]` job done, not sure why I used agg, apply is probably a better description. Since this post I fixed nth to work better so IMO that's the preferred solution here.

Answer (score 41):

Instead of using `first` or `last`, use their string representations in the `agg` method. For example on the OP's case:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ColumnName'])
grouped['D'].agg({'result1' : np.sum, 'result2' : np.mean})

#you can do the string representation for first and last
grouped['D'].agg({'result1' : 'first', 'result2' : 'last'})
```

Comment: This is the much more current approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to also pass a kwarg to the functions, e.g. `numeric_only=True`?

Comment: for future reference: passing dict to `SeriesGroupBy.aggregate` fails in pandas 1.3.5; reformat dict elements as method kwargs such that second example becomes `grouped['D'].agg(result1='first', result2='last')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really the issue, but `sum` and `min` are Python built-ins that take some iterables as input, whereas `first` is a method of pandas Series object, so maybe it's not in your namespace. Moreover it takes something else as an input (the doc says some offset value).

I guess one way to get around it is to create your own `first` function, and define it such that it takes a Series object as an input, e.g.:

```
def first(Series, offset):
    return Series.first(offset)
```

or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom aggregator as shown below.

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[1,"man"], [1, "woman"], [1, "girl"], [2,"man"], [2, "woman"]],columns = 'number family'.split())
d
```

Here is the output:

```
    number family
 0       1    man
 1       1  woman
 2       1   girl
 3       2    man
 4       2  woman
```

Now the Aggregation taking first and last elements.

```
d.groupby(by = "number").agg(firstFamily= ('family', lambda x: list(x)[0]), lastFamily =('family', lambda x: list(x)[-1]))
```

The output of this aggregation is shown below.

```
       firstFamily lastFamily
number                       
1              man       girl
2              man      woman
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
c_df = b_df.groupby('time').agg(first_x=('x', lambda x: list(x)[0]),
                                last_x=('x', lambda x: list(x)[-1]),
                                last_y=('y', lambda x: list(x)[-1]))
```