# Filling in with the last entry of the group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
> df
                   C         D  E
A    B                           
bar  one   -1.350006  0.260339  2
     three -0.236451 -0.056614  0
flux six   -0.515571 -0.155078  1
     three -0.365032  1.055669  2
foo  five   1.145811  1.514191  0
     one   -0.108427 -0.643262  2
     two    0.286897  0.405798  2
     two   -1.452286  1.149264  2
```

If I do:

```
df.groupby(level='A').apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

I get:

```
KeyError: -1
```

Why? I thought I could pass any function to `apply` on a group.

What I want is the following (get the last entry in every group):

```
> df
                   C         D  E
A    B                           
bar  one   -0.236451 -0.056614  2
     three -0.236451 -0.056614  2
flux six   -0.365032  1.055669  2
     three -0.365032  1.055669  2
foo  five  -1.452286  1.149264  2
     one   -1.452286  1.149264  2
     two   -1.452286  1.149264  2
     two   -1.452286  1.149264  2
```

Comment: Does `df.groupby(level='A').last()` not work?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. Not quite. I want to fill a dataframe something with the same exact index

Comment: `df.groupby(level='A').transform(pd.Series.last)` does this work?

Comment: @EdChum I just tried that but I get: `TypeError: last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`

Comment: how about `last = lambda x: x.iloc[-1]  df.groupby(level='A').transform(last)`?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. That doesn't throw an error, but it simply returns the original dataframe. Strange

Comment: I was looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001237/how-to-apply-first-and-last-functions-to-columns-while-using-group-by-in-pan and the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation. You definitely want to use transform in my opinion

Comment: @EdCHum I agree about `transform`, although I thought you can mimic the behavior of `transform` with apply (which is more generic)

Comment: @EdChum Turns out this is a bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7883 I just created a ticket.

Comment: Ah, that's good. Hopefully it'll get fixed in next release, there is probably a workaround I imagine

Comment: For future reference: If you paste your dataframe, please paste it as `df.reset_index()` - otherwise, `pd.read_clipboard()` will not function properly.